# The correct way of representing folders

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm trying to kind of *emulate* a folder structure in my application. Now I've thought of two ways to achieve this, but what is the best practice for that?

Table: `Attachments`

Columns: `Id` (PK), `ParentId` (FK), `Name`, `FileContent`, `IsFolder`

**or**

Table: `Attachments`

Columns: `Id` (PK), `FolderId` (FK), `FileContent`

Table: `AttachmentFolders`

Columns: `Id` (PK), `Name`

Comment: This has been discussed many times. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database

Comment: What are your requirements? Are folders hierarchical? Can folders move? Can files move? What do you need to retrieve fast? How many files/folder? How many folder? Skew?

Comment: Yes, just like any other filesystem: File/Folder move, rename, delete, update should be possible. What do I need to retrieve fast? All of it. How many files? n.